# Eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Consider the zero matrix $M=o$.

Is it correct to say that $M$ then has no eigenvalues and eigenvectors? A natural guess for a candidate would be $\lambda=0$. It solves the characteristic equation $\det (M-\lambda \mathbb I)=0$. But there is no associated eigenvector, that is a *nonzero* vector $v$ such that:
\begin{equation}
Mv=\lambda v=0
\end{equation}
Hence no eigenvectors and no eigenvalues? Or would one say that 0 is an eigenvalue without a corresponding eigenvector?

Comment: Why do you say there is no nonzero $ v $ such that $ Mv = 0 $?

Comment: quite right. I'm not seeing the forest for the trees. Eigenvectors everywhere :) I knew this question was embarrassing, but fortunately I'm not afraid of embarrassment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*All* nonzero vectors are eigenvectors, since *all* vectors $v$ satisfy $Mv=0v$ if $M$ is the zero matrix.

Comment: Thanks @Hans. I can't believe how I have not seen this :)

Comment: I would like to add that therefore the only eigenvalue is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $Mv=\lambda v$ is satisfied by  $\lambda =0$ and every non-zero vector.

Thus you have an eigenvalue of $0$ and all non-zero vectors as your eigenvectors.